# replace string placeholders with array values

Tags: php

I hava a string like:

```
$my_string = "RGB colors are xxx, xxx, xxx";
```

Also have an array:

```
$my_array = ["red", "green", "blue"];
```

I would like to get a string like:

```
echo $my_string; //RGB colors are red, green, blue
```

Is there a one liner that can make this replacements? That is a string with same placeholder that gets replaced with each value from the array.

Comment: I think sprintf() would do what you are asking.

Comment: Do the placeholders need to be `"xxx"`?  Can you change them?  If so, try using [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/sprintf) (possibly with [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array)).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple replace (probably preg\_replace) of same string with array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161639/multiple-replace-probably-preg-replace-of-same-string-with-array)

Answer (score 1):

This is not as straightforward as it could be, because `str_replace` is a global replace - the first call will replace all `xxx`s with the replacement value.  You can use `preg_replace`, and call it multiple times with `$limit=1`.

```
  $my_string = "RGB colors are xxx, xxx, xxx";
  $my_array = [ "red", "green", "blue" ];
  $placeholder = '/xxx/';
  foreach ($my_array as $color) {
    $my_string = preg_replace($placeholder, $color, $my_string, 1);
  }
```

Note that that modifies the original string; you should make a copy and use that instead of `$my_string` inside the loop if you don't want that to happen.

You could also use `sprintf` as suggested in the comments, with a little preparation:

```
  $args = $my_array;
  array_unshift($args, str_replace(['%','xxx'], ['%%','%s'], $my_string));
  $result = call_user_func_array(sprintf, $args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following line can do this. You can allow loop through array to replace all xxx with respective values in array

```
   preg_replace('/xxx/',$my_array[2], preg_replace('/xxx/', $my_array[1], preg_replace('/xxx/', $my_array[0], $my_string, 1), 1), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$my_string = "RGB colors are TO_BE_REPLACE";
$my_array = ["red", "green", "blue"];
echo str_replace('TO_BE_REPLACE', implode(',', $my_array), $my_string); //RGB colors are red, green, blue
```